# magento - how to set custom attributes to order

Tags: php, magento

I installed [Amasty Delivery Date Extension](https://amasty.com/delivery-date.html) on my magento instance. This plugin adds a delivery date and delivery time to my order. 
After the order got created I split the orders and create a few new ones programmatically. Now I need to know how I can set a custom value to the newly created orders. Currently it is just set in the original order.

Comment: you mean you create some orders programatically and you need to set order date and delivery time in them ?  if yes than first of all check sales_flat_order and check for the order attributes for saving time and date . if they exist than you can load the new orders and set those attributes with your values.  thanks

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/20926/how-to-create-store-custom-order-attribute - i think this should help you

Comment: thanks great question, but unfortunally I couldnt find find out how to do this in my case, so I decided to write a raw sql query